# Ruby features that are risky to use

Tags: ruby

As a Ruby programmer did you feel any time about any feature which is a bit risky to use, may be because of it's strange behaviour? It might be well documented but hard to find while debugging or counterintuitive to remember?

I generally try to stay away from `String#gsub!`. The doc says "Performs the substitutions of String#gsub in place, returning str, or **nil** if no substitutions were performed." So if there's nothing to substitute then it'll return nil. Practically I didn't see any use case where this comes handy.

SO, with your experience, is there anything else you'd like to add?

Comment: `gsub!` _won't_ overwrite the string value with `nil` if no substitutions performed. It will only _return_ `nil`.

Comment: `!?!` as an alternative for the `false` keyword ;)

Comment: `% space\ as\ a\ quote\ character `

Comment: @Mladen Jablanović, yeah that's right. I've corrected the language.

Comment: You should *experiment* and find out if features are dangerous. That's what `irb` is for.

Comment: @intellidot: Given the new information about `gsub!`, I don't see why you would avoid it. Which would you rather type? `str = str.gsub(..)` or `str.gsub!(..)`?

Comment: @ryeguy: Those two are *not* equivalent. In particular, the first one will *not* modify the original string.

Comment: I never said the methods were equivalent, but the 2 statements I provided are. The first one does modify the original string, because it's being assigned back to itself.

Comment: Define "risky" better. Nothing I've seen in Ruby scares me compared to burning the atmosphere off the planet, which was rumored to be a concern with the Manhattan project. It is highly unlikely you'll hurt anything with Ruby, unless you are programming something extremely sensitive, and, at that point you'll be very aware of the issues. If you're just learning I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `return` in a `lambda`, `Proc` or block. The semantics [are well defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325471/using-return-in-a-ruby-block), but you will get it wrong, and you will get a `LocalJumpError`.

Comment: How do you get a LocalJumpError by using a return from a lambda?

Comment: Should have been `Proc`, not `proc`. See it now?

Comment: I don't. I understand the dangers of using the return statement in a proc. But when you return from a lambda, it just returns from the lambda created proc and not the calling method. So what I don't understand is how to get a LocalJumpError when returning from a lambda.

Comment: My point is that it's easy to get it the wrong way around, and therefore it's a risky feature. Is `Proc.new { return 1 }` or was it `lambda { return 1 }`? The semantics are clearly defined, but if you're in a rush, are you sure you would always get it right?

Answer (score 1):

The meta programming features of Ruby can be used in very dangerous ways. I've seen code that attempts to runtime-redefine common methods on code classes like String, or Array, and while I can see this being MAYBE acceptable for a tiny temporary script, I don't think it is remotely a good idea in a complex application with many dependancies, or many maintainers.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the most widely abused dangerous feature of Ruby is certainly `eval`ing strings. In vast majority of cases (if not all) it can be avoided using other methods, usually `define_method`, [`const_get`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html#M000485), [`const_set`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html#M000486) etc.

Answer (score 1):

`throw`/`catch` (not the same as `begin`/`rescue`!) is basically `GOTO`, and that could be considered to be a risky feature to use in any language.

Comment: +0 for using "considered" without "harmful".