# Why LocalJumpError?

Tags: ruby, block

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using 'return' in a Ruby block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325471/using-return-in-a-ruby-block)

I'm new to Ruby, and was surprised that this snippet `raise` a `LocalJumpError` when the block `return`:

```
$bail_if = proc { |condition|
  if condition
    puts 'the condition is true'
    return
  else
    puts 'the condition is false'
  end
}

def method some_condition
  $bail_if[some_condition]
end

method true
```

If I defined `bail_if` as a local variable in `def method`, then there is no problem. Why is this?

Comment: Works for me on ruby 1.8.7.  Are you running ruby 1.9?

Comment: Woops, forgot to mention that I'm using 1.9.2p290. Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking this because you want `method` to return if `some_condition` is true, but to continue running the rest of the `method` method otherwise? By the way, `method` isn't an ideal name, because there's already [a method called method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-method)

Comment: @Squeegy: That's because `proc` behaves differently in 1.8 and 1.9 - in 1.8 it returns a lambda, and in 1.9 it returns a proc. See bullet point 2 [here](http://www.skorks.com/2010/05/ruby-procs-and-lambdas-and-the-difference-between-them/)

Comment: @AndrewGrimm, yes I'm asking this because I want `method` to return if `some_condition` is true, but to continue running the rest of the `method` otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `proc { |condition|` to `lambda { |condition|`. proc-object has a block semantic, whereas lambda object has method semantic. Because the proc object is like a block, when you call a proc that executes a return statement, it attempts to return from the method that encloses the block that was converted to the proc. You don't have such method in your first case and as consequence you get `LocalJumpError`. When you define your proc as a local variable in your method, all is working fine.

Comment: It'll not throw an exception, but I don't think it'll do what the OP wants it to do.

Answer (score 2):

You don't `return` from a proc (aka block) in ruby 1.9.  Getting rid of that explicit `return` seems to fix it.  But that `return` is totally useless here anyway.

Or if you do need an explicit return, use a `lambda` instead like @WarHog suggests.