# Why does .each { |rule| return false if !user.match(rule).nil? } not work in Rails C?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using rails console to debug an issue. What works with the rails server errors in rails console and I can not figure out why.

**My code:**

```
email = "team@mysite.com"
user_rules = [/\+/, /\-/, /all/, /updates/, /team/]
user, domain = email.downcase.split('@')
user_rules.each   { |rule| return false if !user.match(rule).nil?   }
```

The last line errors with:

```
1.9.3-p125 :016 > user_rules.each { |rule| return false if !user.match(rule).nil?}
LocalJumpError: unexpected return
    from (irb):16:in `block in irb_binding'
    from (irb):16:in `each'
    from (irb):16
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: This is basically a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325471/using-return-in-a-ruby-block.  The short answer is that you don't want to return from a lambda like that, because it's trying to return from the enclosing function.

Comment: @JimStewart thanks for pointing that out. Would would be the suggested update? Answer below and I'll mark it as correct. thanks

Comment: To clarify, there's nothing explicitly wrong with the code, but it would probably be more clearly written as `return if user_rules.any? { |rule| !user.match(rule).nil? }`.

Comment: Or just `return if user_rules.any? {|rule| user.match(rule) }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using return false in

`user_rules.each   { |rule| return false if !user.match(rule)   }`

but lambda doesnot support return if not used inside function/method.