# `return` in Ruby Array#map

Tags: arrays, ruby, return, enumerator

I have a method where I would like to decide what to return within a map function. I am aware that this can be done with assigning a variable, but this is how I though I could do it;

```
def some_method(array)
    array.map do |x|
      if x > 10
         return x+1 #or whatever
      else
         return x-1
      end
    end
end
```

This does not work as I expect because the first time `return` is hit, it returns from the method, and not in the map function, similar to how the return is used in javascript's map function.

Is there a way to achieve my desired syntax? Or do I need to assign this to a variable, and leave it hanging at the end like this:

```
def some_method(array)
    array.map do |x|
      returnme = x-1
      if x > 10
         returnme = x+1 #or whatever
      end
      returnme
    end
end
```

Comment: Related question with some more answers and details: [Using 'return' in a Ruby block](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2325471).

Comment: `return` in javascript has the opposite behavior. It *does* return from the map function and *not* from any outer method. Sorry, just clarifying cause it sounds like you're saying they behave the same.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You don't need the variable. Return value of the block is value of last expression evaluated in it. In this case, the `if`.

```
def some_method(array)
    array.map do |x|
      if x > 10
         x+1
      else
         x-1
      end
    end
end
```

Ternary operator would look nicer, I think. More expression-ish.

```
def some_method(array)
  array.map do |x|
    (x > 10) ? x+1 : x-1
  end
end
```

If you insist on using `return`, then you could use lambdas. In lambdas, `return` behaves like in normal methods.

```
def some_method(array)
  logic = ->(x) {
    if x > 10
      return x + 1
    else
      return x - 1
    end
  }
  array.map(&logic)
end
```

This form is rarely seen, though. If your code is short, it surely can be rewritten as expressions. If your code is long and complicated enough to warrant multiple exit points, then probably you should try simplifying it.

Comment: Nice! I had to rework my code a bit, but I believe this is a great solution!

Comment: Coming back to this some time later, I am still amazed that `implicit return` works, but not `explicit return`. It is so strange.

Comment: @Automatico: hopefully you'll get used to this :)

Comment: I couldn't. Jumped ship to typescript for most om my projects. @SergioTulentsev

Answer (score 99):

Sergio's answer is very good, but it's worth pointing out that there *is* a keyword that works the way you wanted `return` to work: `next`.

```
array.map do |x|
  if x > 10
    next x + 1
  else
    next x - 1
  end
end
```

This isn't a very good use of `next` because, as Sergio pointed out, you don't need anything there. However, you can use `next` to express it more explicitly:

```
array.map do |x|
  next x + 1 if x > 10
  x - 1
end
```

Comment: That is nice! My actual code is a bit more convoluted than my example above, so `next` could be a very nice solution. Personally I don't like all this "magic by default" behaviour of ruby. It is nice to explicitly state what is going on so it is easier for the next person to pick it up.

Comment: Cool, I have used Ruby a lot but have missed this with `next`. Some day I will start reading manuals...

Answer (score 1):

The `return` keyword can only be used within a method(actually including `Proc`). It will raise the `LocalJumpError`

```rb
irb(main):123:0> array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11, 14, 15]
irb(main):124:0> array.map { |n| return n }
Traceback (most recent call last):
        3: from (irb):124
        2: from (irb):124:in `map'
        1: from (irb):124:in `block in irb_binding'
LocalJumpError (unexpected return)
```

You can use `next` instead of `return`.

```rb
irb(main):126:0> array.map { |n| next n }
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11, 14, 15]
```