# What is wrong with this piece of Ruby code? Why is array empty after map code block?

Tags: ruby

```
r = "FBFB".split("").map do |char|
  if char == "F"
    return 1
  end
  if char == "B"
    return 2 
  end
end
puts r.inspect
```

I get nothing printed to console. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you expecting to receive? 1212?

Comment: An array : [1,2,1,2]

Comment: What was wrong: do not need `return` and correct if-else statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you cannot use `return` inside of a code block, but you should use `next` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2325712/173190)).

Comment: IMHO, you _shouldn't_ use `next` here. Could, but shouldn't. I'd personally do what's described in zswqa's answer.

Comment: Why? You give no explanation.

Comment: Code is easier to read when it has only one exit point instead of several.

Comment: Exit points are still two. Only difference is that code is shorter and it is using implicit return. Maybe that is why your prefer that piece of code?

Comment: Your comment contradicts itself. In absence of explicit returns (or equivalent statements, like `next` in this case), the body will always be executed in full and return the value of the last evaluated expression. That's what I call "one exit point". Always the last expression. And yes, that is precisely why I like that code.

Comment: I do not contradict myself. We have difference of what "body" you mean. I mean the whole function, you mean the separate code paths in the if/else statement.

Comment: Nope, I mean the whole method body. Anyhow, this is getting us nowhere, so I'll stop. Using `next` here works, even if it isn't idiomatic ruby.

Answer (score 1):

```
r = "FBFB".split("").map do |char|
  if char == "F"
    1
  elsif char == "B"
    2 
  end
end

puts r.inspect
```